# How to fetch only count of documents in sensenet by oData query

Tags: odata, sensenet

I have got all document list with all properties by below query

```
/OData.svc/workspaces/Document?$select=*&metadata=no&query=InTree:/Root/Sites/Default_Site/workspaces/Document%20AND%20TypeIs:File
```

But I need only count of those documents

By which oData query I can get only count?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *$count* property, in the following format: 
**https://demo.sensenet.com/OData.svc/workspaces/Document/$count**

You can read more information about OData (releated to this question) in this article ('Addressing the count of a collection' section):

https://community.sensenet.com/docs/odata-rest-api

Br,
maros